# MySQL and PHP Date and Time

Tags: php, mysql, date, time, pdo

```
$date = date('Y-m-d g:i A');

mysql_query("INSERT INTO admin (`firstname`,`lastname`,`status`,`date`) 
VALUES ('$fn','$ln','$login','$date') ") or die(mysql_error());
```

displays: `2013-09-27 8:09 PM` instead of `2013-09-27 8:09 AM`

I'm from the Philippines, time format is UTC +8:00 Beijing, Chongqing, Hong Kong, Urumqi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change:

```
$date = date('Y-m-d g:i A');
```

To:

```
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i');
```

This will use "24 hour" time, which can then be converted to any format you like and is universally recognized.